# How to install Gee Tee Dee (Lightweight Task manager)

Tags: 12.10, software-center

[Official site](http://codea-dev.com/gtd/)

When i download the .deb file and open it with software center it says dependencies not satisfied...

Comment: It requires libnotify, but it's not installable, I'm not sure where libnotify went.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. You can download the `libnotify1` package [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libnotify1)

Then run in a terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb.
```

to install Gee Tee Dee.

Comment: This will make you run into the same issues as with software center. If dependencies can't be satisfied, then `dpkg` can't do magic here.